# PyQ: How to enumerate symbol column on a splayed table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kdb, pyq

I'm trying to create a splayed table with a symbol column using pyq. In q I would set the table by enumerating the symbol column with `.Q.en`...

```
:splay/ set .Q.en[`:splay;]([]a:`x`y`z; b:1 2 3)
```

I tried a few variations of the following...

```
q.set(':splay/', q('.Q.en')('!', ["Name", "Ask", "Bid", "Last", "Vol", "Time"], [K.symbol([]), K.float([]), K.float([]), K.float([]), K.float([]), K.timestamp([])]).flip)
```

But it throws the following rank error: `_k.error: rank`.

What is the proper syntax for this in pyq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your q code is incorrect.  The function

```
.Q.en[`:splay;]
```

will place the `sym` file inside the splay table and this is not what you want.  Instead, the `sym` file should be saved in the top database directory (`db` in the code below) next to the `splay` table.

```
`:db/splay/ set .Q.en[`:db]([]a:`x`y`z; b:1 2 3)
```

The same code can be written in pyq as

```
q.set(':db/splay/', q('.Q.en', ':db', q('([]a:`x`y`z; b:1 2 3)')))
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. That worked to create the splayed table. But I'm going to have to post a follow up question in regards to how to `q.upsert` into a splayed table because it keeps throwing an error. I'm assuming it has to do with enlisting the data I'm appending, since I'm doing it 1 row at a time. I just can't figure out the correct syntax to do this in pyq.